# count of values in a range, obtained with an IF

Tags: excel

I want to create quiz. Column A will contains the correct results column B will be filled by the user with his answers. Column C will contain TRUE or FALSE if values from column B matches the right answers from column A. In cell D1 I want to calculate the percentage of the right answers.

Can someone give me a hint how can I count the TRUE values from column C, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an workaround: Instead of using TRUE and FALSE I am using 1 and 0. On this way, I transformed the COUNT() in SUM() ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function.

=COUNTIF(C:C, "=TRUE")

Comment: The C column get the TRUE or FALSE values as result of a formula. I tried your suggestions and it is working fine if the values would be hard-coded but in my case it doesn't help.

Comment: Try the answer given by Jordan as it will track the formula result of TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: I already tried but I had the same result. Unfortunately, neither this helps me.

Comment: I tried by putting formula "=A2=B2" in column C which results in either TRUE or FALSE. I put both the formulas from answers and it worked. Not sure about your formula in column C.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,TRUE)
```